# How to install a root certificate from file

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

We are in the process of migrating to Exchange 2013 on Server 2012 R2, and will be using third party certificates once fully up and running. In the meantime, however, I have been asked to use a root certificate provided by a contractor (I appreciate this may elicit some comment, this is not my decision).

I have been provided with a text file in the following format to install as a root certificate:

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
okg7OJNVDI9jnvdws8Hughigyig87698HJKHGFj
KHHJKhghvbhKLJGJGVJLGhgfhvkhKJGIV8GK8LJ
...
----END CERTIFICATE----
```

My question is - how do I install this as a root certificate? I've used certificate services briefly before (although it is not installed in this environment) and I don't recall ever having to import something in this format.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save the text as `filename.crt` and double click and in the certificate tool use the "install certificate" button to start certificate import wizard.

This will import the root certicate giving you the ability to validate certificates issues by the that root CA.

The alternative is to fire up `mmc` load the certificates snap-in, browse to the root certificate store and right click tasks ==> import and select the file from there.

Comment: Thanks HBruijn for the quick response. Of course you're right, I don't know why this never occurred to me - mental block! I've now installed the certificate and everything seems to be working as expected, thaks again!